# Delete an Entity with Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to delete an entity using EF6.0 but I'm stuck in a situation and getting exception. Below is the code snippet where I'm running into exception

```
_context.Images.Remove(image)
```

I have a separate logic that gives me this entity. I'm getting below exception:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

Upon googling I found out that since entity is fetched with separate context and getting deleted in separate context i'm getting this error. I don't want to fetch the entity again. I want to use the fetched entity itself but can't find a way to do so.

Comment: *image* from where? it is parameter of method or entity from context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is [Attach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach(v=vs.110).aspx) the entity to the context. This will then give your DbContext knowledge of the object. As long as your entity has a valid ID, you'll be fine.

Here is some pseudo-code to give you an idea of what you'll need to do.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    // Make your context aware of the object.
    context.Images.Attach(image);

    // Now delete the object. It will change the internal
    // state so that it will be deleted.
    context.Images.Remove(image);

    // Finally, save your changes
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Or only `context.Entry(image).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;`. This attaches the image in the `Deleted` state.

Comment: I tried to attach and then remove but now I'm getting exception in `context.SaveChanges`. The exception says `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded`

Comment: Does your `image` have a proper ID that is valid in the database?

Comment: @krillgar yes the image has proper ID which is valid in the database. Still getting this error.